# How to create Gremlin graphs from C#.Net code?

Tags: c#, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am trying to integrate my `C#.Net` Project with `Azure CosmosDb` using `Gremlin` query language. I need help to create a graph from `C#` code instead of manually creating it from the Server. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation located here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-graph-dotnet

It has many C# examples

Cheers Kelvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time, I am not aware of a strongly typed .NET library available for Gremlin which can directly connect to Cosmos.

However, it is quite straightforward to write a wrapper which executes common gremlin functions in C#.

Here's an example of a light ORM I started recently: https://github.com/odds-bods/CosmicGraph/blob/master/CosmicGraph/CosmicGraphClient.cs

```
var vertex = await cosmic.AddVertexIfNotExistsAsync(
    new PersonVertex
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty.ToString(),
        Label = "Fred Smith",
        FirstName = "Fred",
        LastName = "Smith"
    }
);
```

Ideally a functional API (mirroring the Gremlin API) would be better for larger projects, however this would require more work.

Answer (score 1):

Gremlin.Net.CosmosDb

Helper library when using Gremlin.Net in conjunction with a Cosmos DB graph

https://github.com/evo-terren/Gremlin.Net.CosmosDb

Use Strongly-Typed Vertex and Edge Objects 
Create strongly-typed vertex and edge objects to define properties and help with deserialization.

```cs
using Gremlin.Net.CosmosDb.Structure;

[Label("person")]
public class PersonVertex : VertexBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset Birthdate { get; set; }
}

var query = g.V<PersonVertex>().Has(v => v.Name, "Todd").Property(v => v.Birthdate, DateTimeOffset.Now);
var response = await graphClient.QueryAsync(query);

foreach (var vertex in response)
{
    Console.WriteLine(vertex.Birthdate.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(vertex.Name);
}
```

Comment: kindly consider explaining your answer in a greater detail

Comment: I looked at this package as well as Gremlinq. The problem I have with this approach is it requires knowledge of edges at design time. Also it's better to have generic vertices with a "type" label rather than a strongly-typed PersonVertex.

Comment: https://github.com/evo-terren/Gremlin.Net.CosmosDb has been abandoned by the author. The author recommends using https://github.com/ExRam/ExRam.Gremlinq.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that looks active and supports several graph databases is [ExRam.Gremlinq](https://github.com/ExRam/ExRam.Gremlinq)